# Complexity of the following code

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

I was given the following task:

Given - 2 list. Size of the first list is N1, size of the second list is N2. Each list don't have the same elements.
Write a code that create a new list with elements from first and second lists. This list also shouldn't have the same elements.
Also estimate the complexity of your code.

I write the followin code:

```
public class Lists {    
    static ArrayList<Integer> getNewList(ArrayList<Integer> list1, 
                                         ArrayList<Integer> list2) {
        ArrayList<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Integer i : list1) {
            tmp.add(i);
        }
        for (Integer i : list2) {
            if (!list1.contains(i)) 
                tmp.add(i);
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Integer[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 14, 15, 16};        
        Integer[] arr2 = {3, 6, 7, 8, 14};
        ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr1));
        ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr2));
        for (Integer i : getNewList(list1, list2)) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

and say that time of execution of getNewList method would be proportional to N1*N2. In reply I receive the following without any explanation - "You are wrong, the complexity of this code is not N1*N2".

So can someone tell what is the right answer? And explain how complexity is determine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the short answer to your question is: complexity is N1 + (N2*N1)/2 + N3 (size of the new list), which should be in O(N1*N2)

Breakdown:

```
for (Integer i : list1) {
  tmp.add(i);
} 
-> clearly, this is N1
```

---

```
for (Integer i : list2) {
  if (!list1.contains(i)) 
    tmp.add(i);
} 
-> list2 iteration => N2
-> for each of this iteration, you call .contain method 
   which uses sequential search, resulting in N1/2 iterations (on average)
-> So, you get N2*N1/2
```

---

In the main you have a loop, iterating from 0 until N3 (which is the length of the new List)

So, overall you get N1 + (N2*N1)/2 + N3, which should be in O(N1*N2)

Answer (score 9):

The complexity of your code is `O(N1*N2)`, but you can do much better by using a `HashSet` to determine which numbers appear in both Lists :

```
static ArrayList<Integer> getNewList(ArrayList<Integer> list1, 
                                     ArrayList<Integer> list2) {
    ArrayList<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
    HashSet<Integer> dups = new HashSet<>();
    tmp.addAll(list1);
    dups.addAll(list1);
    for (Integer i : list2) {
        if (!dups.contains(i)) 
            tmp.add(i);
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

This would give you `O(N1+N2)` running time, since insertion and lookup take expected `O(1)` time in `HashSet`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm definitely seeing `O(N1 * N2)` complexity here too. I'm guessing your professor overlooked the cost of the `contains` call in the following:

```
for (Integer i : list2) {
    if (!list1.contains(i)) 
        tmp.add(i);
}
```

`contains` on ArrayList is `O(N)` complexity. Since your loop over list2 is also `O(N)`, you end up with `O(N1 * N2)`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for @Slanec's explanation, I recheck the implementation of `contains(Object obj)` in JDK and find it is as below

```
public boolean contains(Object obj) {
    return indexOf(obj) >= 0;
}

public int indexOf(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (elementData[i] == null)
                return i;

    } else {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            if (obj.equals(elementData[j]))
                return j;

    }
    return -1;
}
```

Obviously, the time complexity of `contains(Object obj)` is O(n).(I thought it was O(1) at first)

So the **time complexity** of the code should be **O(N1 * N2**) but not **O(n**).

Comment: Unless you can prove me wrong with an actual explanation, I'm going to say no. The second loop does a `contains()` check for every element in `list2` against `list1`. A `contains()` call on a list is linear, O(N1), the loop itself is obviously linear, too. Therefore the complexity is N1*N2.